# How to use test-framework-th with multiple modules containing tests?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, test-framework

I want to use test-framework-th for generating test groups.

I have this main test module:

```
module Main where

import           Test.Framework.TH

import           Foo.Test

main = $(defaultMainGenerator)
```

And this module containing the test:

```
module Foo.Test where

import           Test.HUnit

case_1 = do 1 @=? 2
```

However, `defaultMainGenerator` does not detect the test in the `Foo.Test` module. It only detects tests in the module in which it is called (in this case `Main`).

How can I split my tests across modules without duplicating boilerplate for every test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`testGroupGenerator`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-th/docs/Test-Framework-TH.html#v%3atestGroupGenerator) in each module to generate a test group for that module, then use those from `main`, e.g.

Foo.hs:

```
module Foo where
import Test.Framework.TH
tests = $(testGroupGenerator)
...
```

Bar.hs:

```
module Bar where
import Test.Framework.TH
tests = $(testGroupGenerator)
...
```

Main.hs:

```
import Test.Framework

import Foo
import Bar

main = defaultMain [Foo.tests, Bar.tests]
```

Comment: Seems like the only option. :[ I think I'll just use a custom preprocessor to generate `main` then.